# How to locate text data in cells and store their location with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm using loop statements to find the text " Measured Values" in a cell in column "B" and store it's cell location.  From this cell location I then want to continue down the "B" column to find each cell that contains the text " 4Wire" and at the same time read the same row but "I" column cell contents and write it to a master .csv file.  I want to stop parsing the file upon finding the cell in column "B" that contains the text " First Article Verification".  My two Do/While loops are not executing as I do not know if the Cells(i, "B").Value is used correctly.  Any ideas as to the problem?   Thanks in advance.

```
Sub ImportKeyDataFromCSVsCOPY()
'Summary:   Import specific data from all CSV files from a folder into a single sheet
Dim wbCSV       As Workbook
Dim wsMstr      As Worksheet
Dim fPath       As String
Dim fCSV        As String
Dim NR          As Long
Dim fPathDone   As String
Dim Count       As Long
Dim i           As Long
Dim k           As Long
Dim d           As String
Dim MVnotFound  As Boolean
Dim Cells       As String


fPath = "F:\i9 Tester\VB Macro spreadsheet\"    'path to CSV files, include the final \ in this string
fPathDone = fPath & "Imported\"                 'remember final \ in this string
On Error Resume Next
MkDir fPathDone                                 'creates the completed folder if missing
On Error GoTo 0
Set wsMstr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterCSV")   'sheet in thisworkbook to collate data into

NR = wsMstr.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1   'next empty row to add
Count = 1   'Initialize count to 1
Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'speed up macro
fCSV = Dir(fPath & "*.csv")         'start the CSV file listing
    Do While Len(fCSV) > 0
        i = 0
        MVnotFound = True

        Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fCSV)    'open a CSV file
        Do While MVnotFound                         'loop to find " Measured Values" text    i = i + 1
            If Cells(i, "B").Value = " Measured Value" Then
                MVnotFound = False
            End If
        Loop
        Do
            If Cells(i, "B").Value = " 4Wire" Then
                wsMstr.Range("H" & NR).Value = Cells(i, "I").Value
            ElseIf Cells(i, "B").Value = " Fist Article Verification" Then
                d = "  First Article Verification"
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop While d <> " First Article Verification"

        wbCSV.Close False           'close the opened CSV
        NR = NR + 1                 'increment next target row
        Name fPath & fCSV As fPathDone & fCSV           'move file to IMPORTED folder
        fCSV = Dir                  'ready next CSV filename
    Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Cells(i,"B") is a valid argument.  i cannot be zero (try starting at i+1) and the column cannot be a letter.  For example use Cells(1,2) to refer to B1 (Column 2 Row 1)

Comment: @AAMC08 ,Cells(i,"B")-- "i" cannot be 0 like you say, but "B" will work as column 2